# how to join this tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

im new to rails

**error**

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'states.ad_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `states`.* FROM `states` WHERE (`states`.ad_id = 1) LIMIT 1
```

**my model**

ad.rb

```
has_one :state
```

state.rb

```
belongs_to :ad
```

**here are my tables.**

*ads* table

```
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+-----------+
| id | title          | description | price | states_id |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | ebook          | asdasd      |     1 |         1 |
|  2 | iphone 4 devol | sdfsdf      |     1 |         1 |
|  3 | asd            | asd         |     1 |         2 |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

*states* table

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Pluto    |
|  2 | Mars     |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message tells you that you dont have ad_id column in the states table.
You probably wanted to use states.id instead of states.ad_id

Answer (score 1):

see the Is it a belongs_to or has_one association?  section of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

in your example you probably want

state

`has_many :ads`

ad

`belongs_to :state`

as you are specifying a many to one as opposed to a one to one relationship,  since a state can have many ads

Comment: Yes. The belongs_to always goes on the side with the foreign key.